# Не могу верно отправить запрос google api

Tags: python

Всем привет.
Пишу программу для использования google api. Я создал сервисную учетную запись и api ключ.
Для теста хочу сделать вот такой запрос:

```
def get_user():
    url = "https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/some@email.ru"

    headers = {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }
    params = {
        "key": "API_KEY"
    }

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, json=params)
    return response.text
```

Но мне возвращается ошибка:

```
400 Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.
```

Я делаю вывод, что меня авторизует по ключу, но видимо какой то не верный запрос.
Может кто то пользовался этим и знает как правильно передавать параметры?